# I want to increase screen resolution on Raspbian Pixel for PC on DELL Optiplex 755 and ASUS monitor

Tags: raspbian, screen

Problem: cannot increase screen resolution on Raspbian Pixel for PC on DELL Optiplex 755 and ASUS monitor.

The monitor is an ASUS VW202S with a single VGA port
It works fine at screen resolution of 1680x1050 from a Pi 3 running Raspbian Stretch with a HDMI/VGA adapter.

However, I have a DEL Optiplex 755 with Pixel for PC installed.
The DELL only has a DVI video port, so I am using a DVI to VGA cable to the same ASUS monitor as above.
The maximum resolution I get is 1024x768, but I want 1680x1050 (like when using the Pi)

The PC version of Raspbian does not have the Resolution menu option under
Preferences / Raspberry Pi Configuration / System

Also there is no config.txt file in the /boot folder.

So I cannot use the suggestions made by many on the forums

I did find some suggestions on a Ubuntu forum, suggesting using xrandr, as follows:

xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync

and

xrandr --addmode VGA1 1680x1050_60.00

But how do I now use that new resolution?
On Ubuntu, simply go to Settings - but where to go on Raspbian Pixel for PC ?

Comment: Milliways - My monitor only has a VGA port so I have no option, anyway I can get the correct 1680x1050 resolution using a Pi.

Comment: fruitoftheloom (www.raspberrypi.org/forums) - Thank-you, your solution - it did the trick

After the xrandr (newmode and addmode) commands ... 
Display settings GUI can be shown by: Menu - Preferences - Main Menu Editor - Prferences - Display Settings (tick) - OK 
Menu - Preferences - Display Settings
... then change to new resolution set by xrandr commands 

I just need to make it permanent now, else I will lose it on reboot, but I have some ideas to try. 

Thanks again.